# Nodejs inserting into database fails

Tags: mysql, node.js

I've been trying to make this script work with value binds, but seems it doesn't work with the mainTable variable.

```
var mainTable = "tasks";
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "host",
    user: "user",
    password: "password",
    database: "database"
});

con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    var values = {
        id: "id",
        url: "url",
        assignee: "akjdh",
        status: "ahsbdu",
        type: "apsokdn",
        description: "asd",
        department: "department"
    };

    var query = con.query("INSERT INTO ? SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ?", [
            mainTable,
            values,
            values
        ], function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 record inserted");
    });
});
```

I get the following error:

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''tasks' SET `id` = 'id', `url` = 'url', `assignee` = 'akjdh', `status` = 'ahsbdu' at line 1

I don't understand why its failing with if I make the table value into a bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql identifiers have to be escaped using a backtick `` ` `` and not using `'`.

- `?` is used to escape value with `'`
- `??` is used to escape identifiers with `` ` ``

As of that it hast to be:

```
INSERT INTO ?? SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ?
```

[mysql: Escaping query identifiers](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-identifiers)

> Alternatively, you can use ?? characters as placeholders for identifiers you would like to have escaped like this: